# Can I carry a power bank traveling from Dubai to Goa on Oman Air?

Tags: luggage, power, oman-air

Can you please advise me if I can carry a power bank on flight/hand luggage, when traveling from Dubai to Goa on Oman Air?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Travel. Please take a look at https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and then tell us what research you've already done to try and answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can't have them in checked luggage, but you can carry up to two in the carry-on luggage.

Source: [Times of Oman](https://timesofoman.com/article/97139):

“Carrying power banks in check-in baggage is not allowed in Oman Air. However, each passenger is allowed to carry two power banks in the carry-on bags (hand baggage),” a spokesperson of Oman Air said.